# Debugging Intel Compiled Project with GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, codeblocks, intel-composer

I've got a simple Hello World project in the Code::Blocks IDE which I'm compiling using the Intel C++ compiler.

I've set the compiler option '/Zi' in the projects Build Settings so I can debug the application with breakpoints. However no breakpoints are ever reached.
It appears that no debugging symbols can be found within the object.

They are correctly reached when I change to use the gcc compiler however.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't this work as is?

[Update]

Seems to work on Linux but not on Windows. I ran the same sort of test a simple project with Intel compiler and the correct compiler option and I could reach breakpoints. Is there some reason Windows would have a problem?

Comment: Use the Intel debugger (`idb`) which comes with the Intel compiler.

Comment: IDB doesn't appear to work with the Code:Blocks IDE unfortunately otherwise I would.

Comment: OK - but you can still use it outside of the IDE (i.e. from the command line).

Comment: That's a possibility. But I'm sure it's possible to get it working in the IDE. I'd like to explore solutions there encase I needlessly complicate the debugging and build process.

Comment: The `idb` debugger has been replaced with the `gdb-oneapi` debugger. If your Windows application includes support for a GPU the Intel `gdb-oneapi` debugger is used to debug the GPU code. All code that runs on the CPU is debugged using the Microsoft Visual Studio debuggers. Switching between debugging GPU code and debugging CPU code is handled automatically in Visual Studio, if you installed the Visual Studio oneAPI extensions. If you are using VSCode the VSCode `gdb-oneapi` extension only supports debugging on Linux (remotely or locally) and uses `gdb-oneapi` to debug CPU and GPU code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some reason Windows would have a problem?

On UNIX, the debug info is usually completely documented, and often standard (e.g. Linux uses [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF)).

On Windows, Microsoft compilers use .PDB ([Program Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)) files, which are completely undocumented and proprietary. GDB can't use them.

I don't know what debug info format Intel compiler generates, but chances are that format is *only* understood by `idb`.

Effectively then, you can't mix and match GDB with any of the Microsoft or Intel compilers.

Comment: I've changed to use the Microsoft Debugger CDB which is compatible with Code::Blocks