# gdb-oneapi "No debugging symbols found in <exe>"

Tags: c, gdb, intel-oneapi

I don't know how to add debugging symbols to my compiled C code on windows. My attempt so far is below.

My test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My compilation attempts

```
icl.exe main.c /debug -o testmain.exe
icl.exe main.c /debug /Z7 -o testmain.exe
icx.exe main.c /debug /Z7 -o testmain.exe
icl.exe main.c /debug /Zi -o testmain.exe
```

My execution

```
gdb-oneapi testmain.exe
```

The compilation generates three files: .exe, .ilk, .pdb. gdb complains that no symbols have been found in the exe.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515634/debugging-intel-compiled-project-with-gdb and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032013/debugging-intel-c-compiled-code-with-gdb both of which indicate that the Intel compiler doesn't generate the debugger output needed by gdb. However see this toolkit https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-for-gdb.html#gs.y1596p

Comment: It was the intel gdb distribution that originally gave me hope. "gdb-oneapi" works fine on linux but seems to fail on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suggest you use the Visual Studio debugger to debug the C/C++ applications.
On the Windows platform, the Intel C/C++ compiler is compatible with the Microsoft toolchain. Please refer to the below link.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-1/microsoft-compatibility.html

And thus emits debugging information in a format compatible with Visual Studio and the VS debugger. This format is not supported by gdb-oneapi.
On Windows, gdb-oneapi provides Visual Studio integration that supports debugging of code offloaded to a GPU. Please refer to the below link.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/user-guide-vs-code/2023-1/gdb-gpu-support-for-intel-oneapi-toolkits.html

For additional references:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/distribution-for-gdb/get-started-guide-windows/2023-1/overview.html
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/distribution-for-gdb/tutorial-debugging-dpcpp-windows/2023-1/overview.html

Comment: Clarification: If your Windows application includes support for a GPU the Intel `gdb-oneapi` debugger is used to debug only the GPU code. All code that runs on the CPU is debugged using the  Microsoft debuggers. This switching is handled automatically if you installed the Visual Studio oneAPI extensions. Note also that the VSCode debug support referenced in the link in the second paragraph does not apply to Windows or Visual Studio. The VSCode `gdb-oneapi` extension only works on a Linux platform and manages switching between CPU debugging as well as GPU debugging on Linux.